# Increase related products on single product page (woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm doing some work on a website running wordpress - woocommerce styled by Jupiter theme.

The problem is that I've asked the developers for help but that's been a while already.

I'm looking for a way to increase the "related products" at the bottom from 2 to 4 so it fills out the template.

In related.php, i thought i found the values to change the amount of related products, but i was wrong. It does nothing at all, which is strange in itself for me.

OLD

```
 <?php
/**
 * Related Products
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $product, $woocommerce_loop;

$related = $product->get_related( $posts_per_page );

if ( sizeof( $related ) == 0 ) return;

$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
    'post_type'            => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
        'no_found_rows'        => 1,
    'posts_per_page'       => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby'              => $orderby,
    'post__in'             => $related,
    'post__not_in'         => array( $product->id )
) );

$products = new WP_Query( $args );

$woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;

if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div class="related products">

        <h2><?php _e( 'Related Products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    </div>

<?php endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

NEW

```
<?php
/**
 * Related Products
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

 if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

 global $product, $woocommerce_loop;

 $related = $product->get_related( 6 );

 if ( sizeof( $related ) == 0 ) return;

 $args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
    'post_type'            => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
    'no_found_rows'        => 1,
    'posts_per_page'       => 6,
    'orderby'              => $orderby,
    'post__in'             => $related,
    'post__not_in'         => array( $product->id )
 ) );

 $products = new WP_Query( $args );

 $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = 4;

 if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div class="related products">

        <h2><?php _e( 'Related Products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    </div>

      <?php endif;

 wp_reset_postdata();
```

So I'm really baffled right now, hope anyone has suggestions or solutions on how to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redefine a WooCommerce function to override the default values it contains:

In your `functions.php` add this:

```
// Redefine woocommerce_output_related_products()
function woocommerce_output_related_products() {
     woocommerce_related_products(4,2); // Display 4 products in rows of 2
}
```

You'll need to edit the numbers in brackets to suit your requirements.

Comment: Awesome, I tried this before after finding it online. But the location of the paste is also key is it not? because when I pasted it at the beginning of my theme's functions.php it didn't do anything for me. But when pasted at the end it worked, I think it has to do with the fact I was trying to override before functions was called?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference but, as you've said, if you've defined this function elsewhere and you then re-define it somewhere BEFORE the already defined function then, yes, it won't have an effect. Glad you got it working.